# Asp dropdownlist defaulting to disabled

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an asp website in which i created a web user control which contains a dropdown list populated by a data source.

```
    <asp:dropdownlist id="lstBusinessUnit" runat="server" 
                            appenddatabounditems="True"
                            width="200px" 
                            datasourceid="sqlBusinessUnit" 
                            datatextfield="sBusUnitDisplay" 
                            datavaluefield="sBusUnitCode"
                            enabled="true">
        <asp:listitem value="0" text="[Select]" selected="True" />
    </asp:dropdownlist>

    <asp:sqldatasource id="sqlBusinessUnit" runat="server" 
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database %>" 
    selectcommand="SELECT [sBusUnitCode], [sBusUnitDisplay] FROM [tBusinessUnits] ORDER BY [sBusUnitDisplay]" />
```

When i run the webpage which contain the dropdownlist is disbaled.

I inspect with firebug and this is the result :

```
 <select style="width:200px;" id="ucTimesheetAxapta_lstBusinessUnit" disabled="disabled" name="ucTimesheetAxapta$lstBusinessUnit">

</select>
```

Comment: Check if Web User Control containing that dropdown isn't disabled somewhere else in the code or in markup.

Comment: where you're having dropdown? inside the panel??

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian no inside a normal .aspx page in a <td style="HEIGHT: 15px" colspan="2">
                <uc3:timesheetaxapta id="ucTimesheetAxapta" runat="server" />
               </td>

Comment: Can you do a simple test - add another control e.g. button in the same user control next to drop down, run the page and see if that new control is also disabled when page loads.

Comment: @PrzemG yeah the button is also disabled

Comment: can you please post the aspx page control coding here..! the problem might be over there..!!

Comment: @PrzemG Sorry guys. Controls were inside a panel that is found to be disabled deep down in the code. Thanks for your help and pointing all this out.

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian  Sorry guys. Controls were inside a panel that is found to be disabled deep down in the code. Thanks for your help and pointing all this out.

Comment: It means that one of containers is disabled. Get Id of each control that contains your user control and search entire solution for that id. there must be piece of code somewhere (client or server code) that disables it.